# bash: print: command not found

Tags: linux, bash

I've just added a .profile to my bash shell. However, I've noticed the error "-bash: print: commant not found" keeps on appearing even if you are changing to a valid directory. My .profile just contains a few exports.

```
[rob@mypc:/home/rob]cd apps
-bash: print: command not found
[rob@mypc:/home/rob/apps]cd util
-bash: print: command not found
[rob@mypc:/home/rob/apps/util]
```

Can anyone point out why this error keeps on showing?

Comment: Is there any other way without changing the command inside the file? As much as possible, it is a configuration file and I would like to across various shells.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Check the output of:

```
echo $PROMPT_COMMAND
```

it might give some clues, or else you might have cd aliased to something, so check the output of:

```
alias
```

Comment: echo $PROMPT_COMMAND returns an empty string.

Comment: Then you might have cd aliased, as I said; the other answers about changing print to echo also apply, if you happen to find a print command anywhere.

Answer (score 12):

use `printf` or `echo`

Answer (score 2):

Change the occurence of `print` in `~/.profile`, `~/.bash_profile`, or `/etc/profile` (system wide) to `echo`.

Answer (score 0):

Look in your .bash_profile and .bashrc and see if anything is using the print command.

Answer (score 0):

Substitute `print` with `printf`. At least in my case, I had the following in `.bash_profile`

```
function tabname {
  print "\e]1;$1\a"
}
```

to change the name  of a Terminal tab. When I tried changing `print` to `echo`, it just echoed the text exactly, i.e., `\e]1;new tab name\a`, but when I used `printf`, then it worked as expected.